# snowsql python load csv file to tempstorage using put

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, put

**Using Python + Snowsql**
Am trying to load a CSV file using **PUT command to copy the local file(s) into the Snowflake staging area for the table.**

```
file_path = 'file://XXXXX/YYYYYY/ZZZZZZ/TEST/Final.csv'.format(os.getcwd())
con.execute("PUT '{0}' @test_results".format(file_path))
```

The above command is not working so may be I have to load the data to snowflake stage and use Copy to Command to load to the table.

**Question** : How to identify the snowflake user stage name or the stage name where the files can be loaded before copying the same to Table in snowflake
I dont have an option to view the stage in Snowflake UI
[image]

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please see [Ask]

Comment: Are you getting an error. If yes, you should share what's happening.

Comment: We need more information about the error, but I am guessing that your path might not be correct.  If you work in linux/mac and using an absolute path to the file, then it will start as "file:///" (three slashes). See examples in the [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html#examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list the stages created in your account you can use the command:

```
show stages in account;
```

To list the stages created in the selected database and schema you can run just:

```
show stages;
```

It is also possible to use the user stage '@~'

Answer (score 0):

This code worked

Find existing state . From CMD run Show stages

file_path = 'file://C:/Files_to_Load/Final.csv'.format(os.getcwd())
con.execute("PUT '{0}' @**TEST_STAGE**".format(file_path))